# CSS: Is it possible to achieve the following layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible to achieve the following responsive design layout shown in the image below using CSS3 Flexbox? I am able to achieve the desktop layout using the code below. However, I can't think of a way to make div `#div3` and `#div4` fill below `#div1` and `#div2`

[image]

EDIT: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that it is not restricted to CSS Flexbox only, and it seems like the grid solution would be more flexible so I will just mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help guys!

My code

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div4 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container,
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

#flex-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id='div1'></div>

    <div id="flex-container">
      <div id='div2'></div>
      <div id='div3'></div>
      <div id='div4'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you use the new grid css layout (display: grid) ? it would be very easy with grid ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using grid in this case would make it much easier.

Every `div` here has a `grid-area` set to some value that is used to indicate how it should behave in the grid according to layout rules defined in `.container` `grid-template-areas` every string there defines one row in the grid. The `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` are used to define number of rows and columns

```css
 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #div1 {
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      grid-area: div1;
    }

    #div2 {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      grid-area: div2;
    }

    #div3 {
      background-color: orange;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      grid-area: div3;
    }

    #div4 {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      grid-area: div4;
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      height: 100%;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas: "div1 div2" "div3 div3" "div4 div4";
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-areas: "div1 div2" "div1 div3" "div1 div4";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='div1'></div>
  <div id='div2'></div>
  <div id='div3'></div>
  <div id='div4'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First, you could put all the `div`s inside the same container:

```
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id='div1'></div>
  <div id='div2'></div>
  <div id='div3'></div>
  <div id='div4'></div>
</div>
```

Then, in container you set `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. You put `width` `50%` if you want half screen and `100%` full screen. The flex-wrap setup will organize items as it should be.

In mobile @media, you change `flex-direction` to `row` and `width` of each `div` to match the layout you want.

It would be like this:

```
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px; // or 33.333%
  width: 50%;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px; // or 33.333%
}

#div4 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px; // or 33.333%
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { // screen width you prefer
  #flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  #div1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #div2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #div3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #div4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.
You could even simplify CSS using classes for repeated properties.

Comment: Keep in mind that with this approach you **have to** define a height for the container, that might cause issues

Comment: Exactly, but I believe there is an intention to do so.